# Clickable place names on Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, names

I was wondering if it were possible to access the names which are displayed on Google Maps and allow you to create events.

For example, would it be possible to make the name "London" (UK) clickable and have a hyperlink to some other page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it were possible to access the names which are displayed on Google Maps and allow you to create events.

No it isn't, they are part of the tiles.

> For example, would it be possible to make the name "London" (UK) clickable and have a hyperlink to some other page?

You could however add a click listener to the map, [reverse geocode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding) the location of the click and perform some action based on that result.